# How can Method Chaining be done in JS?

Tags: javascript, methods, method-chaining

I want to chain these method calls:

```
utils.map([1,2,3,4,5], function (el) { return ++el; } )
```

and

```
utils.filter(function (el) {return !el%2; }
```

They are working fine individually, but the following is not working correctly. How can I make the following code work?

```
utils
    .map([1,2,3,4,5], function (el) { return ++el; })
    .filter(function (el) { return !el%2; }
```

Here is my `utils` object:

```
var utils = {
    each: function (collection, iteratee){
        return collection.forEach(iteratee);
    },
    map: function (collection, iteratee) {
        return collection.map(iteratee);
    },
    filter: function (collection, predicate) {
        return collection.filter(predicate);
    },
    find: function (collection, predicate) {
        return collection.find(predicate);
    }
}
```

I understand that when I chain two methods, the arguments change and I have to provide only the iteratee and not a collection. How can this be done?

Thanks in advance. If needed, I am open to explanation of a particular concept.

Comment: Did you find a useful answer? Please leave a comment, and/or accept one of the answers.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to chain functions like that, each function needs to return "this".

Comment: but what about the actual manipulation, per say for find method, I find and return the key value pair, how would I return that if I return "this".

Comment: That's your design decision. If you want to be able to chain, which is a very valid pattern, you lose the ability to return a 'primitive' result. You need to put your result in a property of utils, to be interrogated when you're finished. Or you could look at promises, where the output of one step becomes the input to the next. But promises really only make sense for asynchronous operations.

Answer (score 0):

Be aware that in order to make `forEach` chainable, you need to add a `return` statement. As in [MDN docs on forEach](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach):

> unlike `map()` or `reduce()` it always returns the value undefined and is not chainable. The typical use case is to execute side effects at the end of a chain.

Secondly, the original methods like `map` and `filter` are already suitable for chaining. As you already mentioned at the end of your question, your methods require the first argument to be the *subject* of the method, which is a pattern that is incompatible with chaining. With chaining, the subject must be the object that exposes the method.

You could allow chaining by passing each time a new `utils`-like object through the chain. For creating these new instances of `utils` it is easier to define it as a function object, because that allows you to create new `utils` objects with the `new` keyword. Since it then really is a constructor, it is appropriate to write `Utils` with a capital:

```js
function Utils(collection) { // "constructor"
    this.collection = collection;
    this.each = function(iteratee){
        this.collection.forEach.call(this.collection, iteratee);
        return this;
    },
    this.map = function(iteratee){
        return new Utils(this.collection.map.call(this.collection, iteratee));
    },
    this.filter = function(predicate){
        return new Utils(this.collection.filter.call(this.collection, predicate));
    },
    this.find = function(predicate){
        return new Utils(this.collection.find.call(collection, predicate));
    }
};

// test it
result = new Utils([1,2,3,4,5])
          .map(function (el) { return ++el; })
          .filter(function (el) { return !(el%2); });

document.write(JSON.stringify(result.collection));
```

Outputs:

> [2,4,6]

Here `Utils` is a constructor, and returns an object with methods that act on the private collection property. Each method returns a new `Utils` object, except in the case of `forEach` as it can just return the current object.

So in this script the test call to `map` is really a call to `Utils.map`.

It should be said that this does not give much benefit over the native way that `map`, `filter`, ... can be chained. But I suppose you have other plans to extend this pattern.

Minor note: in the expression `!el%2` you probably wanted to first evaluate the modulo operator, and then the `!`, but it executes in the other direction. So I added parentheses in the code above.

Comment: This only works if the OP wants to use Array methods in the second step (and not his `utils` methods).

Comment: Updated the answer completely, with snippet demonstrating the chaining of the example code given in the question.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an updated version of trincot's response with an ES6 class design.

```js
class Collection {
  constructor(collection) {
    if (collection == null || !Array.isArray(collection)) {
      throw new Error('collection is null or not an array');
    }
    this.collection = collection;
  }
  each(iteratee) {
    this.collection.forEach.call(this.collection, iteratee);
    return this;
  }
  map(iteratee) {
    return new Collection(this.collection.map.call(this.collection, iteratee));
  }
  filter(predicate) {
    return new Collection(this.collection.filter.call(this.collection, predicate));
  }
  find(predicate) {
    return this.collection.find.call(this.collection, predicate);
  }
  contains(value) {
    return this.collection.includes.call(this.collection, value);
  }
  get() {
    return this.collection;
  }
}

const result = new Collection([1, 2, 3, 4, 5])
  .map(el => ++el)
  .filter(el => !(el % 2))
  .get();

console.log(result);

console.log(new Collection([1, 2, 3, 4, 5]).find(e => e === 2));
console.log(new Collection([1, 2, 3, 4, 5]).contains(2));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { top: 0; max-height: 100% !important; }
```